# Anyone know what this paper backing under this ceiling texture is?

Tags: painting, ceiling, texture

I'm hoping someone knows what appears to be some kind of paper backing under ceiling texture is. Some areas are just peeling right off. Mainly around cracks. Other areas are very difficult and it almost seems like some kind of old adhesive.

I'm not sure what all the layers on top of the plaster are. I thought it was just some old textured paint that was peeling off of the plaster. But there seems to be some type of paper backing under it that was adhered to the plaster. The house was built in 1921 and from what I can tell this is the only room where the ceiling is like this. Ideally I'd like to scrape it all away to the plaster. There are a lot of areas peeling.

Any ideas on how to get the areas that don't want to come loose off?

Thanks.[image][image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Thanks for the pictures; what is each layer? Are you hoping to remove it all?

Comment: Hello Daniel, thanks for responding. I'm not sure what all the layers on top of the plaster are. I thought it was just some old textured paint that was peeling off of the plaster. But there seems to be some type of paper backing under it that was adhered to the plaster. The house was built in 1921 and from what I can tell this is the only room where the ceiling is like this. Ideally I'd like to scrape it all away to the plaster. There are a lot of areas peeling.

Comment: Good info. What in these pictures is what you're calling a "paper backing"? And, would you edit this info into your question? It makes it easier to get a complete understanding of what you're looking for.

Comment: It is possible that the "paper backing" was a paper covering applied to the ceiling similar in manner that wall paper is applied to a wall for decorative purposes. One could venture to call that "ceiling paper" but in reality it may have just been wall paper used on the ceiling. Later on the spray on textured material was applied. It is not clear from the pictures if the texture was applied over a fully papered ceiling or if portions of the ceiling paper were removed beforehand. --- I placed this in a comment because this is just a guess and not a sure answer.

Comment: @DanielGriscom What I think is "paper backing" is the orange looking material in the pictures. It feels and peels off like paper that has been stuck to something.

Comment: @MichaelKarasThis is actually my thought as well. I was thinking someone applied ceiling paper, or wall paper to help cover up the cracks in the plaster. they then applied the texture over the top of that.  I sprayed it down with water and the texture comes right off after letting it set for a while. the under layer, or "paper backing" still seems to be just as difficult to remove.